# Generic Singleton Factory

Tags: java, generics

While reading online, I came across the following:

```
public interface UnaryFunction<T>
{
    T apply(T arg);
}

.......


private static UnaryFuntion<Object> ID_FUNC = new UnaryFunction<Object>
                                          {
                                             Object apply(Object arg)
                                             {
                                                  return arg;
                                             }
                                          };

public static <T> UnaryFunction<T> idFunction()
{
    return (UnaryFunction<T>) ID_FUNC;
}
```

In `main`:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String[] strings = {"Peter", "Paul", "Mary"};
    UnaryFunction<String> names = idFunction();
    for(String s : strings)
    {
        System.out.println(names.apply(s));
    }

    Number[] numbers = {1, 2.0, 3L};
    UnaryFunction<Number> nums = idFunction();
    for(Number n : numbers)
    {
        System.out.println(nums.apply(n));
    }
}
```

My question is, why do we need a generic `interface` here?

Would simply the following suffice:

```
public interface UnaryFunction
{
    Object apply(Object arg); //Object as return type and argument type, instead.
}
```

? What is the need here to use generics?

And, what is actually a generic singleton factory? What is it good for?

Thanks.

Comment: apparently the OP is talking about something in Effective Java, 2nd ed. Item 27: Favor Generic Methods page 131 ?

Comment: @NathanHughes Yes, sir. You're well-read.

Answer (score 3):

The generic singleton factory is the idFunction in your example. Without it you would have a choice between two ugly alternatives, either require a cast wherever you use it, like this:

```
public class ExampleWithoutGenericSingletonFactory {

    static UnaryFunction<Object> ID_FUNC = new UnaryFunction<Object>() {
        public Object apply(Object arg) {
            return arg;
        }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("1234.1241234");
        BigDecimal b1 = (BigDecimal)(ID_FUNC.apply(b)); // have to cast here >_<
        System.out.println("engineeringstring val of b1 = " 
        + b1.toEngineeringString());
    }
}
```

or make separate implementations for every type you want to support:

```
public static UnaryFunction<String> ID_FUNC_STRING = new UnaryFunction<String>() {
    public String apply(String arg) {
        return arg;
    }
};

public static UnaryFunction<Number> ID_FUNC_NUM = new UnaryFunction<Number>() {
    public Number apply(Number arg) {
        return arg;
    }
};

public static UnaryFunction<BigDecimal> ID_FUNC_DECIMAL = new UnaryFunction<BigDecimal>() {
    public Number apply(BigDecimal arg) {
        return arg;
    }
};
```

giving you some ugly verbose cut-n-pasted code with a different name for every type that you have to keep straight. But since you know it's a pure function and the types get erased, you can have only one implementation (ID_FUNC) and have the singleton factory idFunction return it.

You would use this for cases where you have one function implementation that you want to be able to specify different types on, where the implementation is stateless.

The example could be better, since it only calls toString on the objects returned from the function call there's no demonstrated benefit from the factory. If the example showed using type-specific methods on the objects returned then the benefit might be more apparent.

An unchecked cast warning comes up when you do this, but it's safe to suppress it (which is what Joshua Bloch advises).

Comment: Thanks for response. But would a non-generic interface be OK? Like my suggested example above not using `T` as the return value nor the arg value  but use `Object`?

Comment: @Unheilig: you could but you'd have to cast whenever you use it. the example gets by without the cast because it doesn't do anything but call toString, but if you wanted to do anything subtype-specific with it you'd need the cast.

Comment: The part I am most confused is: on the `interface` it is declared as `T` while in the function definition (i.e. `ID_FUNC`) it is declared as `Object`, hence my question why the author chose to use a generic interface when he then declare the function as `Object` instead of `T` as in the `interface`.

Comment: @Unheilig: because he wants to implement the function only once and use the return type without casts. The assignment of idFunction infers the type from the variable the return value is assigned to. sorry if i'm missing the question, added another example.

Comment: Other words, why didn't he do this instead: 
`private static UnaryFuntion<T> ID_FUNC = new UnaryFunction<T>
{
    Object apply(T arg)
    {
         return arg;
    }};` ? Thanks.

Comment: Based on that, what would be the need to declare an interface with type `T` when he eventually "re-define" the function definition (as above) using `Object`? Sorry.

Comment: `private static UnaryFuntion<T> ID_FUNC = new UnaryFunction<T> {     Object apply(T arg)     {          return arg;     }};` This will not compile as generics can't be passed in static members. You will get error `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static type T`